# Why can't you encode an object with protocol types?

Tags: swift, codable

I can't get class `A` to auto-synthesize codability below

```
protocol MyCodableProtocol: Codable { }

class B: MyCodableProtocol { }

class A: Codable {
    var foo: MyCodableProtocol = B()
}
```

> cannot automatically synthesize 'Encodable' because 'MyCodableProtocol' does not conform to 'Encodable'

I also get the issue in the more simplified problem

```
class C: Codable {
    var foo: Codable = "foo"
}
```

Why yields the even more amusing message:

> ... because 'Codable' (aka 'Decodable & Encodable') does not conform to 'Encodable'

What is going on?

Comment: The good ol' problem of [protocols not conforming to themselves](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43408193/2976878) :) Think about how decoding into a `Codable` should work, what concrete type should be constructed?

Comment: You can see that the issue is indeed what Hamish has already stated, by trying your examples separately with `Decodable` and `Encodable`. Neither can automatically synthesise the protocol stubs, but you can easily make `C` conform to `Encodable`, while you cannot make it conform to `Encodable`, since the `decode` function expects a concrete type to be decoded, which cannot be inferred by the compiler if you declare your variable to be of type `Codable`.

Comment: [Protocols not conforming to themselves](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43408193/2976878) is a useful resource, but I am not sure why its been marked as a duplicate.  I have given it some thought and figured out why you can not encode an object with protocol properties its not related to a language issue.  I was going to answer this but can't because someone has duped it.